# git asks for password for user git

Tags: git

I'm trying to set up a project I have locally on my orgs git server.  Their instructions seem to be similar to your standard git repos, so this seems to be the typical way to go:

```
cd existing_folder
git init
git remote add origin git@our-git-url:my-user-name/my-project-name.git
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin master
```

But when I do this, it prompts me for `git@our-git-url`'s password.  Am I supposed to know what that is?

I next tried what I thought would make more sense, which was instead using the line `git remote add origin my-user-name@our-git-url:my-user-name/my-project-name.git`.  But then I get a permission denied error, even though the credentials its associated with should match up to the user that created the project in the first place, me.  What am I not getting here?

Comment: You probably need to add an ssh key to your account, but there's not enough information here for anybody to provide a concrete solution.

Comment: No, I actually think that helps.  Stand by.

Comment: Actually, I already uploaded my ssh key to the site.  This does seem like something that should happen with some regularity for folks though.  When the instructions say to add the origin using the username `git`, what kind of credentials are supposed to be supplied for that?

Comment: Your own Git is going to, at the point of contacting the Git repository at the URL `git@our-git-url:my-user-name/my-project-name.git`, invoke `ssh git@our-git-url git-upload-pack` (or similar). That makes your ssh command try to log in to that host as user `git`. Their ssh server will demand an ssh key; your ssh will supply a key as directed by your ssh configuration and set of keys.

Comment: Typically, when you attempt to log in to a host as user `git`, there's a special login shell for that user that inspects the incoming key and compares it to a large set of keys. From that large set, one key matches (or of course, no key matches): that one key is associated with "our employee Frank Harris" or whatever other data they store in their database. From that, they know who you are and what repositories you're allowed to do what with.

Comment: Okay, that scans.  It looks to me like my ssh key ducks should be in a row, but for some reason they aren't.  I ended up avoiding the problem by following instructions for http protocols instead of ssh.  That will do until I manage to figure out why it doesn't seem to recognize my key.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the comments of your post, you mention you created a SSH key and updated it on the server but still cannot solve your problem.

Few things to guide you throught:

- SSH keys are not loaded by default. You can do that with `ssh-add ~/.ssh/your-private-key`. If you don’t want to type this in every terminal you open, I recommend setting up the ssh agent. [GitHub has a nice tutorial explaning how to do this](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent).
- SSH keys will not necessarily eliminate the password prompt. To achieve that, you need to use a password-less key.